# Story about Adolf Hitler and Eva Braun traveling in the USA

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

In a short story I read about 40 years ago about a man in the 1950s USA who met a confused old man and a younger woman, the whole plot twist was that the couple were Adolf Hitler and Eva Braun.

I also remember the short story was in a pocket book with collected stories all by the same writer.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is surely the short story *The Wandering Gentile* by C.S. Forester, showing another side to his Napoleonic naval stories.

The story concerns the unnamed narrator picking up an elderly couple hitchhking to San Francisco. He overhears scraps of German spoken by the couple, and in conjunction with references to "interntional jewry" and a pet dog named "Blondi" concludes that the couple are none other than Adolf Hitler and Eva Braun. Explaining this later to a policeman, he wonders if the experience was supernatural, with Hitler doomed to forever wander the Earth in penance as a counterpart to the Wandering Jew.

It was collected in a book of Forester's short stories about Nazi Germany entitled *[The Nightmare](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1793055.The_Nightmare)*, first published in 1954.

Comment: Thank you for giving that great and very correct answer when I gave so little information!

Comment: @H.A.Treesong My pleasure! I thought I knew the story as soon as I read the title - there aren't that many stories about the Hitlers hitchhiking in the US!

Comment: I must reread that collection, because I have no memory of that story!